# Filtrar por fecha menor que en django rest framework

Tags: python, django, date, djangorestframework, filtro

estoy tratando de obtener los ejercicios que su fecha es menor que una fecha pasada por parámetro. Pero al escribir el signo menor que (<) recibo un herror que el inicio no es definido, si embargo inicio no se declara, es asi como se llama el campo de fecha del modelo Ejercicio. Cuando pongo solamente el sigono igual (=) no me da herror alguno, entonces eso me lleva a pensar que no estoy intentando filtrar de la manera correcta y que deve excistir otro modo de hacerlo para filtrar por menor que o mayor que. Si te surge alguna duda no dudes en dejarme un comenterio. Saludos.

```
@action(detail=False, methods=['get'], url_path='ejercicio_unidad', url_name='ejercicio_unidad')
def ejeporfechaentidad(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    fechaprocesamiento = request.query_params.get('fechaprocesamiento')
    try:
        ejercicios_por_fecha_unidad = Ejercicio.objects.filter(inicio<=fechaprocesamiento)

        serializer = EjercicioSerializer(ejercicios_por_fecha_unidad, many=True)

        return Response(serializer.data)
    except EjercicioSerializer.DoesNotExist as e:
        return Response(str(e), status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asi es, para filtrar fechas se usan los gt, gte, lt, lte.

Basicamente equivalen a mayor que, mayor o igual que, menor que, y menor o igual que, respectivamente.

Por ejemplo si quiero filtrar todas las entradas donde pub_date es mayor que la fecha 2005-1-3:

```
Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__gt=datetime.date(2005, 1, 3)
```

pd: recuerda que para acceder a estos filtros el campo al que filtras el gt debe preceder con el doble guion bajo, asi: " field__gt"